# unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist launching ChromeDriver using robot framework with headless in Docker

Tags: docker, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I have robot framework which will try to run the UI testing in headless mode. But when we run the robot framework inside Docker container, we got the below error

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start:
> exited abnormally. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't
> exist) (The process started from chrome location
> /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is
> assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV JAVA_OPTS "-Dlog4j.formatMsgNoLookups=true"
ENV LOG4J_FORMAT_MSG_NO_LOOKUPS=true
ENV WAIT_VERSION 2.7.2

#Install Google Chrome
RUN echo 'deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/chrome.list
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN set -x && apt-get update && apt-get install -y xvfb google-chrome-stable

#Install Chrome Driver
RUN BROWSER_MAJOR=$(google-chrome --version | sed 's/Google Chrome \([0-9]*\).*/\1/g') && \
    wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_${BROWSER_MAJOR} -O chrome_version && \
    wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`cat chrome_version`/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \ 
    unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin/

ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/$WAIT_VERSION/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

RobotFramework resource details

```
##### Headless Browser ##########
    ###### For Headless #######
    ${chrome options} =     Evaluate    selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    ...                     modules=selenium, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${chromeOptions}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    headless
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    disable-gpu
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    --ignore-certificate-errors
    ${var}=     Call Method     ${chrome_options}    to_capabilities 
    Create Webdriver   driver_name=Chrome   alias=google   chrome_options=${chrome_options}     
    Go To   ${environment.url}
    Maximize Browser Window
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get across the error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally. 
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

you can add the argument *`--no-sandbox`* as follows:

```
##### Headless Browser ##########
    ###### For Headless #######
    ${chrome options} =     Evaluate    selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    ...                     modules=selenium, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${chromeOptions}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    headless
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    --no-sandbox   # newly added argument
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    disable-gpu
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    --ignore-certificate-errors
    ${var}=     Call Method     ${chrome_options}    to_capabilities 
    Create Webdriver   driver_name=Chrome   alias=google   chrome_options=${chrome_options}     
    Go To   ${environment.url}
    Maximize Browser Window
```